# How to make a python timer change a variable value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a timer, so that at the end of the timer, the timer changes the value of 'timerdone'. At the end of my timer, it doesn't change the value.

**Example Code:**

```
from time import sleep

timerdone = False

def timer():
    print "3"
    sleep(1)
    print "2"
    sleep(1)
    print "1"
    sleep(1)
    timerdone = True

timer()

if timerdone == True:
    print "BOOM!"
else:
    print "Something wrong."
```

When I run this in terminal, it prints "Something wrong." instead of "BOOM". I know that I can just make it print "BOOM!" at the end of the timer, but this is just a simpler way of showing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning `timerdone`, so all you're doing is creating a new variable name `timedone` in the function and setting it to false. You should return it instead.

```
from time import sleep

def timer():
    print "3"
    sleep(1)
    print "2"
    sleep(1)
    print "1"
    sleep(1)
    return True   


if timer():
    print "BOOM!"
else:
    print "Something wrong."
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value. So:

```
from time import sleep

timerdone = False

def timer():
    print "3"
    sleep(1)
    print "2"
    sleep(1)
    print "1"
    sleep(1)
    return True

timerdone = timer()

if timerdone == True:
    print "BOOM!"
else:
    print "Something wrong."
```

Global variables will also work but returning a value is usually a better practice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your variable `global`.

```
def timer():
    global timerdone
    print "3"
    sleep(1)
    print "2"
    sleep(1)
    print "1"
    sleep(1)
    timerdone = True
```

If you do not use the keyword `global`, the variable `timerdone` refers to the local scope of the function `timer()`.

Note that you can access and so read global variable without specifying the keyword, but `global` is needed if you want to change its value.